# flutter ios app runs on xcode but won't run on vscode and android studio

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

My app runs perfectly on android and ios (using xcode only). For some reason, when I run it using vsCode or Android studio, it returns an error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           1206.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-07-13 18:28:30.237 XCBBuildService[1870:62140] Failed to remove: /Users/macUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eexwsmocuanrnufgsdyvbcjnzgqw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/c98de69306103c117579f3f2cbe3019a-desc.xcbuild: unlink(/Users/macUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eexwsmocuanrnufgsdyvbcjnzgqw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/c98de69306103c117579f3f2cbe3019a-desc.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/xds/xds_channel_secure.cc:34:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/writing.cc:21:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/context_list.h:26:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/internal.h:109:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_chttp2_ping_queue
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/internal.h:110:52: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_closure_list lists[GRPC_CHTTP2_PCL_COUNT] = {};
                                                       ^~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/internal.h:112:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_chttp2_ping_queue' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_chttp2_ping_queue;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/tls/tls_security_connector.cc:21:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/tls/tls_security_connector.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/tls/tls_security_connector.cc:32:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/ssl/ssl_credentials.h:25:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl/ssl_security_connector.h:60:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_ssl_server_config
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl/ssl_security_connector.h:61:51: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      tsi_ssl_pem_key_cert_pair* pem_key_cert_pairs = nullptr;
                                                      ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl/ssl_security_connector.h:66:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_ssl_server_config' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_ssl_server_config;
      ^
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/tls/tls_credentials.cc:21:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/tls/tls_credentials.h:26:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/server/secure_server_credentials.cc:26:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/client/secure_credentials.cc:19:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/client/secure_credentials.h:29:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_create_auth_context.cc:24:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.cc:19:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/server/secure_server_credentials.cc:26:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/client/secure_credentials.cc:19:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/client/secure_credentials.h:29:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_create_auth_context.cc:24:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.cc:19:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/secure_auth_context.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Source/API/FIRLoadBundleTask.mm:41:29: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        _bytesLoaded = progress.bytes_loaded();
                     ~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Source/API/FIRLoadBundleTask.mm:43:28: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        _totalBytes = progress.total_bytes();
                    ~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Source/API/FIRLoadBundleTask.mm:97:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'firebase::firestore::api::LoadBundleTask::LoadBundleHandle' (aka 'long long') to 'FIRLoadBundleObserverHandle' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
      return _task->Observe(std::move(core_observer));
      ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is what I get when I run flutter doctor -v

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-BH)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/alialqallaf/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (12 days ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alialqallaf/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: mazaya
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  apple_sign_in_safety: ^0.0.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.2.0
  firebase_core: ^1.2.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.7
  firebase_storage: ^8.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  get: ^4.1.4
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  modal_progress_hud_nsn: ^0.1.0-nullsafety-1
  pdf: ^3.3.0
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  responsive_framework: ^0.1.0
  share_plus: ^2.1.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.8

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.1.8+4

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/dev/mazaya.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FFFFFF"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/dev/mazaya_adaptive.png"

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: "assets/dev/splash.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/svg/
    - assets/images/
  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I tried so many solution that I found such as

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ios/Pods  
rm ios/Podfile 
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.FinderInfo .   
flutter pub cache repair 
rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec  
pod deintegrate && rm Podfile.lock && pod install  
flutter clean
```

I also changed the channel from the master to the stable one but none of this worked.
Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been solved!

I changed the configurations of the project on Xcode as it is in the image below
[image]

I took the image from: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56085#issuecomment-645088488

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /Users/macUser/Work/Mazaya/mazaya/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
> ```

this is the part that have a problem
go to your Pod file and change target to 9 or higher
change at **platform :iOS, 9.0** as the first line of my image

[image]

Comment: it was set to 10.0, but unfortunately 11.0 did not work as well.

Comment: Could you try to build with flutter run -v  to see more details. Another thing is you can try to run via Xcode instead, sometimes Xcode gives you more information from iOS side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ali Alqallaf 
in Xcode change info->Release->Runner->Pods-Runner.release to Release
My APP can run in Android Studio

[choise Release not Pods-runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJjDj.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am facing the same issue at the moment and neither my solution nor yours works for me. Can you please explain why this is happening? and do you have any other solutions that might work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the project is not inside a Onedrive folder. This causes the project to not run properly.

See [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123583)